# Debugging mysql sproc, right syntax near 'NULL'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have written a sproc that will be triggered on inserting a new record to the table.

When called it returns an error `1064` and states:

> 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1'

The problem I'm having is I can't debug the inner query to find out where 'NULL' is. Or why its appearing.

Would appreciate if anyone can suggest how I could debug this, or, spot whats up with my code. N.B. I dont believe I can test the dynamic query outside of a sproc.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SetUniqueCodeCustomLength;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SetUniqueCodeCustomLength (
    IN TableName VARCHAR(255), 
    IN FieldName VARCHAR(255), 
    IN PKName VARCHAR(250), 
    IN PKID INT, 
    IN CodeLength INT)
BEGIN

    SET @pass = '';
    SET @loop = 0;
    SET @matchCount = 1;
    SET @sSQL = '';

    WHILE @matchCount > 0 DO

        SET @loop = 0;
        WHILE @loop < CodeLength DO
            -- random number from x-uy
            SET @chr = SUBSTRING('abcdefghjkpqrstuvwxyz23456789', CAST( ROUND(RAND()*(29-1)+1) AS INT), 1);         
            SET @pass = @pass + @chr;
            SET @loop = @loop + 1;
        END WHILE;

        -- Check for unique-ness.
        SET @sSQL = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @matchCount FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @FieldName + ' = ''' + @pass + '''');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sSQL;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    END WHILE;


    SELECT @pass;
    -- perform the update
    SET @sSQL = CONCAT('UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET ' + @FieldName + ' = ''' + @pass + ''' WHERE ' + @PKName + ' = ' + @PKID);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sSQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Calling with:

```
CALL SetUniqueCodeCustomLength('Posts', 'PostCode', 'PostID', 7, 6);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations:

- Stored procedure's parameters ([13.1.16 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)) are different from User-Defined Variables ([9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)), eg.: `IN TableName != @TableName`.
- Check [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) syntax.
- Be careful with prepared statements (security) and possible SQL Injections.

```sql
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SetUniqueCodeCustomLength`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER $$

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `SetUniqueCodeCustomLength` (
    ->   IN `TableName` VARCHAR(255)
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SET @`sSQL` := CONCAT('SELECT ', @`TableName`); -- NULL
    ->   SELECT @`sSQL`;
    -> 
    ->   SET @`sSQL` := CONCAT('SELECT ', `TableName`); -- SELECT Posts
    ->   SELECT @`sSQL`;
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `SetUniqueCodeCustomLength`('Posts');
+---------+
| @`sSQL` |
+---------+
| NULL    |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+--------------+
| @`sSQL`      |
+--------------+
| SELECT Posts |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```